# Overlay of one div with another div not working on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am showing articles in a matrix of 2x3 and i wrapper article details image, title, author & Desc inside wrapper div & i want this whole div to be overlaped by another div of same dimension which contains one image.

I tried but it is not working for me below is the partial code i am working on

```
   <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
      <div id="article2x3-image">
         <img src="../images/article/3897b78e-6770-4cf0-a8e5-8638e733c0f4.jpg" class="imgArticle2x3Image" />
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-title">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" >Article Title </span>
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-author">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" >by Author XYZ</span>
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-desc">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" >Some Description of teh article wil do here</span>
      </div>
     <div class="overlay2x3"><img alt="google" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" /></div>
   </div>


   <div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP"  >
      <div class="overlay2x3"><img alt="google" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" /></div>

      <div id="article2x3-image">
         <img src="../images/article/0e7207e6-d5e6-4f10-9224-988fe0ca338e.png" class="imgArticle2x3Image" />
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-title">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" >Article Title</span>
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-author">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" >>by Author XYZ<</span>
      </div>
      <div id="article2x3-desc">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" >>Some Description of teh article wil do here</span>
      </div>
   </div>


$("#article2x3-outer-wrapperHP").hover(
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay2x3").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500)},
    function(){$(this).find(".overlay2x3").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500)}
);
```

Complete code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qeqm/8/)

I am not sure why hover is not triggering, I would appreciate help in this regard

Comment: Replace both `<div id="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">` with `<div class="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">`, because you can't have two elements with same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, but you need to position the various divs: see http://jsfiddle.net/4qeqm/9/

The overlay div must be positioned absolutely, the wrapper must have `position: relative;`.

EDIT: Please review your HTML, you are using the same ID on different elements. This will generate problems. Try using classes for similar objects.

Comment: I will have about 6 DIV wrappers with same ID `#article2x3-article-wrapperHP` & i want it to do hover for that particular div only. Cant we change script in such a manner so that it will work for all div & trigger hover for particular div only .. I will try meanwhile to use it for class so that it works for all.. in your case it works for only first DIV. Anyways appreciate you response.

Comment: I have modified it to work with all the `DIV's` by using class name rather than ID Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4qeqm/10/

Answer (score 1):

The selector for "#article2x3-outer-wrapperHP" is the main problem here, you define it twice.  Drop the use of IDs and turn to classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/e54cz/

HTML

```
 <div class="article2x3-article-wrapperHP">
      <div class="article2x3-image">
         <img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/2788088920/ddc41d50d200366d3fbcb4483ee2154e.jpeg" class="imgArticle2x3Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-title">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" >Article Title </span>
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-author">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" >by Author XYZ</span>
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-desc">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" >Some Description of teh article wil do here</span>
      </div>
     <div class="overlay2x3"><img alt="google" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/61/Apple_Safari.png" /></div>
   </div>


   <div class="article2x3-article-wrapperHP"  >
      <div class="overlay2x3"><img alt="google" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/61/Apple_Safari.png" /></div>

      <div class="article2x3-image">
         <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLU7TVcauaFMxvO9VVqi82GHljZECxqxT6RvZ6Q7KQ1nlD4wC7nv1ATgE" class="imgArticle2x3Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-title">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Title" >Article Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-author">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Author" >>by Author XYZ<</span>
      </div>
      <div class="article2x3-desc">
         <span class="lblArticle2x3Desc" >>Some Description of teh article wil do here</span>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.article2x3-article-wrapperHP {
float:left;
width:233px;
height:324px;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:25px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.overlay2x3
{
    height:324px;
    width:233px;
    background-color:Red;
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
  z-index:1000;
}
.article2x3-image
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:233px;
    height:155px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.article2x3-title
{
    min-height:20px;
    max-height:36px;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    width:230px;
    overflow:hidden;

    font-size:14px;
}
#article2x3-author
{
    height:14px;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    width:230px;
    overflow:hidden;
     font-size:10px;
     font-style:italic;
     color:Gray
}
.article2x3-desc
{
    height:100px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    width:230px;
    overflow:hidden;
     font-size:12px;
     border:0px solid #f5f5f5;
     text-align:justify;
}
.imgArticle2x3Image
{
    width:230px;
    border:0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #777;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #999;
}
```

Comment: The multiple use of an ID is only part of the problem (it covers the second box). Combined with absolute positioning (see my answer) it will also work for the first box, hence for both. ;)